# Get acces to Sudoers files on MacOS without any Admin rights

Tags: macbook-pro, password, administrator, sudo

I just got a new macbook that my uncle used for a short amount of time, unfortunately tough, he lost his password and now doesn't have access to his old account (only admin account). Before that, he made me a new account without any admins rights, I have MacOS 14.3.1. How do I get access to the Sudoers file to change the admin password, or get the admin password, Or do anything. I am seriously lost, I tried so much already and followed every article and still nothing worked. I am also kind of scared to going into recovery mode since I heard that people got stuck in recovery mode and couldn't get out and had to reset their MacBook, which I don't want to do since there are some files there which a kind of important. Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/102633